# Problems with calling the same Coroutine two consecutive times in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm trying to rotate the planes of a Rubik's cube using `Coroutines`, here's my code:

```
IEnumerator RotateUpperFacecw(){
    while(Mathf.Abs(totalRotation) < 90f){
        totalRotation += 10;
        Parent.transform.RotateAround(red.transform.position,Vector3.up,10);
        yield return 0;
    }

    if(Mathf.Abs(totalRotation)>=90f){
        totalRotation=0;
        Update(UpperFace);
    }
}
```

however when I try to call the coroutine two consecutive times like this

```
StartCoroutine(RotateUpperFacecw());
StartCoroutine(RotateUpperFacecw());
```

it gives a wrong result.

I tried to call the first one, wait for a second then call it again and it was fine, but I don't get it, shouldn't the (yield return 0) block the execution until the end of this coroutine?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

`yield return 0` is the same as `yield return false` and it waits for a frame

Comment: so how am I supposed to wait until the end of this coroutine?

Comment: I dont know any out of the box way , I think you could somehow measure the amount of time it takes to finish and use `yield return new waitforseconds`

Comment: or you can "yield return StartCoroutine(RotateUpperFacecw());" should work but you must make your calling method IEnumerator and start it as a coroutine

Comment: thanks! I used a flag with  yield return new waitforseconds and it worked perfectly! :D

Answer (score 0):

The second coroutine call won't wait for the first to finish, at some point they will run at the same time, both trying rotating the object. You can call the second time inside the first call but you will need a boolean or something to avoid calling indefinitely.